# How to set permission to directory /var/log in MacOS

Tags: macos, permissions

I find that current user has no accessible permission to `/var/log`.

What permission is the best for it?

how to show the current user's access permission of a folder/file?

```
user:bin soul$ ls -la /var/ | grep log
drwxr-xr-x  56 root          wheel         1904  2 26 21:14 log
user:bin soul$ ./searchd -c ../etc/sphinx.conf
Sphinx 3.1.1 (commit 612d99f)
Copyright (c) 2001-2018, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '../etc/sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: failed to open log file '/var/log/searchd.log': Permission denied
shutdown complete
user:bin soul$ 
user:bin soul$ whoami
soul
user:bin soul$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer `chmod`. Example :

You can set the permissions like this :

`sudo chmod +wrx folder/or/file/path` will add read, write and executable permissions for the folder or file specified ( Note: this will do it for all users. ).

For specifying for each user category, you can do something like this:

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx path/to/file/or/folder
```

**or**

```
sudo chmod 755 path/to/file/or/folder
```

This will set it to the current permission set as shown for the `/var/log` directory.

You can also run `man chmod` for more details on usage of the command.

> What permission is the best for it?

The default permissions enough and recommended.

> how to show the current user's access permission of a folder / file?

Current user's permission can be determined from the first column.
From the string `rwxr-xr-x` in `drwxr-xr-x` you can infer that the `user` has read, write and executable permissions ( denoted by `rwx` ), whereas the group and other users only have read and executable permissions ( denoted by `r-x` ).

Comment: thank you very much.is there exists command show  whether some user has access permission to some folder or file.

Comment: `ls -la` itself shows the permissions. Let's say if the current user is the owner, then the first three characters after the first character in string `drwxr-xr-x` tell us the permissions for the owner. If the current user is a group user, then the next 3 character tell us the permission and if the current user is in other, the last three characters tell us the permissions. You can always find the group of a user by typing `group username`.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer, so that other members can know that this question is solved.